# Why Firebug is not showing updated checked value in input using Uniform jQuery

Tags: jquery, firebug, jquery-uniform

One thing I noticed while using Uniform jQuery (http://uniformjs.com/#example):

Open your Firebug and change radio buttons; you can see that it is adding a class in the `<span>` tag.

`<span class='checked'>`

But the bad thing is that the radio button value is not updating in Firebug.

`<input type='radio' name='btn1' />`

I used this library and tried to submit the form anyway; to my surprise, it correctly submits the selected radio button value.

Is this a problem within Firebug? If not, how can I see that change affected in the "checked" input field?

Comment: Where is this input tag that you mentioned? The closest I've found is `<input type="radio" value="radio1" name="rgroup">` in the most recent Firefox (22.0)

Comment: I am talking about radio button. the issue is not related with firefox version.